# Deleting elements in a row

Tags: python, numpy

I want to get an answer for c where c is defined as:

c= x+y

I have the following entry for x and y:

```
x y
-2 5
-3 10
2 15
4 20
6 25
```

to get the data, I loaded it from a csv file:

```
data=np.loadtxt('data.csv',delimiter=',',skiprows=1)
x_value= data[:,0]
y_value= data[:,1]
```

The code works fine until I decided to remove the negative entry for x. I have:

```
x_value1= [x for x in x_value if float(x)>0]
```

It now returns an error. I understand that for it to work, I also have to remove 5 and 10 in y since the entries for the equation are not the same. I don't have any idea how should I do it.

Comment: which error is returned?

Comment: @Ashalynd: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066249/filtering-lines-in-a-numpy-array-according-to-values-in-a-range

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to want to ditch the list comprehension for this, since it's a longer operation and it will involve multiple lists. You could just use indices, and copy the non-negative data into new lists:

```
new_x = []
new_y = []
for i in range(len(x)):
  if x[i] >= 0:
    new_x.append(x[i])
    new_y.append(y[i])
```

Alternate strategy using `zip`:

```
new_x = []
new_y = []
for x_elem, y_elem in zip(x,y):
  if x_elem >= 0:
    new_x.append(x_elem)
    new_y.append(y_elem)
```

I'm not sure if there's a more condensed way of doing this, but I prefer longer, more readable code anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use your logic on `data` instead, checking for negative on the first entry of each 2-tuple:

```
>>> data
array([[-2,  5],
       [-3, 10],
       [ 2, 15],
       [ 4, 20],
       [ 6, 25]])

>>> data2 = n.array([x for x in data if float(x[0])>0]) # x here is each row
>>> data2
array([[ 2, 15],
       [ 4, 20],
       [ 6, 25]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can try something like:

```
data[data[:,0]>0]
```

as hinted in the similar answer:[filtering lines in a numpy array according to values in a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066249/filtering-lines-in-a-numpy-array-according-to-values-in-a-range)